# Make the first letter of each sentence capital without changing the rest of the sentence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sentence like below:

```
sent = "It was cold yesterday in Chicago. you are sneezing since morning. come in and take rest."
```

Now, I need to make the first letter after every period as capital without touching the rest of the sentence. Something like this:

```
"It was cold yesterday in Chicago. You are sneezing since morning. Come in and take rest."
```

I tried below code:

```
'. '.join(list(map(lambda x: x.strip().capitalize(), sent.split('.'))))
```

But this changes the first word to capital and the rest all will change to lower case, like below:

```
"It was cold yesterday in chicago. You are sneezing since morning. Come in and take rest."
```

We can observe that 'Chicago' changes to 'chicago' which I do not want. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
'. '.join(list(map(lambda x: x[0].capitalize() + x[1:], sent.split('. '))))
```

Or even better using a generator:

```
'. '.join(x[0].capitalize() + x[1:] for x in sent.split('. '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string capitalize method and apply it to the first word of each sentence.

```
sent = "It was cold yesterday in Chicago. you are sneezing since morning. come in and take rest."
new_sent = ""
for item in sent.split('. '):
    item = item.replace('.', '')
    first_word = item[0].capitalize()
    rest = item[1:]
    new_sent += first_word + rest + ". "

print(new_sent)
#It was cold yesterday in Chicago. You are sneezing since morning. Come in and take rest.
```

Comment: This is converting Chicago into chicago, that’s exactly OP’s problem.

Comment: @ZainArshad. I fixed it.  See the new code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `capitalize()` function for the whole line, as it returns a string with the first letter capitalized and all other characters lowercased (which will change the other correctly formatted words like `Chicago` in your case). The following code should solve your problem:

```
sent = "It was cold yesterday in Chicago. you are sneezing since morning. come in and take rest."
new_sent = ""
for item in sent.split('.'):
    item = item.strip()
    if len(item):
        new_sent += item[0].upper() + item[1:] + ". "

print(new_sent)
```

Output:

```
"It was cold yesterday in Chicago. You are sneezing since morning. Come in and take rest. "
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex`. First, separate your message into multiple sentences then capitalize your first word of the sentence.

```
import re
sent = "It was cold yesterday in Chicago. you are sneezing since morning. come in and take rest."

def MakeCapitalize(text):
    sentences = re.findall('[^.!?]+[.!?](?:\s|\Z)', text)
    print(sentences)
    sentences = [x[0].upper() + x[1:] for x in sentences]
    return ''.join(sentences)

print(MakeCapitalize(sent))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have a few options to choose from. Here's a solution to consider using regex to solve this.

You can give this:

```
import re
sent = re.sub(r'(\. \w)', lambda m: m.group(0).upper(),sent)


>>> re.sub(r'(\. \w)', lambda m: m.group(0).upper(),sent)

'It was cold yesterday in Chicago. You are sneezing since morning. Come in and take rest.'
```

If there is more than one space after the period (.), then use this.

```
sent = "It was cold yesterday in Chicago.  you are sneezing since morning. come in and take rest."
sent = re.sub(r'(\. *\w)', lambda m: m.group(0).upper(),sent)
print (sent)
```

Output will be:

```
It was cold yesterday in Chicago.  You are sneezing since morning. Come in and take rest.
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
string = "It was cold yesterday in Chicago. you are sneezing since morning. come in 
and take rest. "
result = []
sentence = list(string.split('. '))
sentence.pop(-1)
for i in sentence:
    result.append(i[0].upper()+i[1:])
print(". ".join(result))
```

Just make sure the last full stop has a space after it.